# SCSM 2012 R2 - Unable to get list of Work Items using cmdlets

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to use the inbuilt Powershell cmdlets for SCSM 2012 R2 in order to query the work items (Incidents, Service Requests, Problems) on a test box.

The command that I am trying to run is

```
`Get-SCSMClassInstance -Class (Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.Incident)`
```

The command runs without errors but I get no results even though I have ~20 test incidents. I have been tearing my hair out as I have tried various suggested methods on my journey with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Get-SCSMObject -Class (Get-SCSMClass -Name 'System.WorkItem.Incident$')
```

Because Get-SCSMClass may return one match, use the '$' to anchor the name it matches on. (if you run it without, you'll probably see about 4 classes returned).